# How to write a regex in title case - SAP Information Steward

Tags: regex, plsql, sap, regex-group

I'm working with an SAP Information Steward and creating a rule where names will have to be in title case (i.e. each word is capitalized).

I've formulated the following rule:

```
BEGIN

IF(match_regex($name, '(^(\b[A-Z]\w*\s*)+$)', null)) RETURN TRUE;

ELSE RETURN FALSE;

END
```

Although it is successful it appears to accept inputs which should be identified as 'FALSE'. Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

'TesT Name' and 'TEST NAME' should be FALSE but are instead passing under this regex.

Any help/guidance with the regex would be very useful.

Comment: `\w` matches both cases. Change it to `[a-z]`.

Comment: `^[A-Z][a-z]*(\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/x4LHds/1)) should do.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew That worked! Thank you so much - it worked like a charm

Comment: Can there be digits in the names? Or underscores?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm guessing in my scenario yes - both digits and underscores can be present. Would the regex then become this:  `^[A-Z][a-z0-9_\-]*(\s+[A-Z][a-z0-9_\-]*)*$`

Comment: Yes, if hyphens are also allowed. BTW, no need to escape the hyphens at the end of the character class. Note `^[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]*(\s+[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]*)*$` will also allow consecutive hyphens.

Comment: Thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew ! I was stuck on this problem and you've really helped to clear it up - Great job!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `(^(\b[A-Z]\w*\s*)+$)` regex presents a pattern that matches a string that fully matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\b[A-Z]\w*\s*)+` - 1 or more occurrences (due to `(...)+`) of

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `\w*` - 0 or more letters/digits/underscores
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

As you see, it allows trailing whitespace, and `\w` matches what `[A-Za-z0-9_]` matches, i.e. it matches both lower- and uppercase letters.

You want to only match lowercase letters after initial uppercase ones, also allowing `-` and `_` chars. You may use

```
^[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]*(\s+[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]*)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hpF70Q/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]*` - an uppercase letter followed with 0+ lowercase letters, digits, `_` or `-` chars
- `(\s+[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]*)*` - zero or more occurrences of:

  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
  - `[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]*` - an uppercase letter followed with 0+ lowercase letters, digits, `_` or `-` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

I would write your regex as:

```
^[A-Z]\w*(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)*$
```

This says to match a single word starting with a capital letter, then followed by one or more spaces and another word starting with a capital, this quantity zero or more times.

I phrase a matching word as starting with `[A-Z]` followed by `\w*`, meaning zero or more word characters.  This allows for things like `A` to match.

### Demo

**Edit:**

Based on the comments above, if you want some other character class to represent what follows the initial uppercase letter, then do that instead:

```
^[A-Z][something]*(?:\s+[A-Z][something]*)*$
```

where `[something]` is your character class.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast response. It makes a lot more sense. But it still appears with the same results when I'm applying the rule to my test variables. Could it possible just be the software i'm using?

Comment: @Z.K.I `^[A-Z]\w*(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)*$` is basically the same pattern as yours, but does not allow trailing whitespaces.

Comment: @Z.K.I If you want to allow for trailing whitespace, I can modify my pattern.  I assumed that you would not want this.